# gwt seam application doubt

Tags: gwt, seam, seam2

i have an application running on JBoss Seam 2, which uses rich faces as its presentation layer.

My question is can I do away with rich faces and use gwt.

what are the stuff that  must take into account ?

Is it possible ?

Comment: <SEAM_HOME>/examples/remoting/gwt has a working sample which uses GWT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use gwt instead of richfaces if you would like to. You can start by reading [Chapter 22](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/2.0.0.GA/reference/en/html/gwt.html) of the seam reference guide.